# Can we calculate Net Salary with openERp

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, erp

In our company we decided to use `openERP` 
We now working to customize `openERP` with our work ... we can use it successfully in warehouse dept. and sallies  dept.

`My question is` how to make `openERP`  calculate `monthly Net Salary` 
with deduct if the Employee absence or leave the work or if we decided to add bonus

`and if we can`  programming new model and add it How this difficult to work and what about expected time  required to do

OR how we can access to fields related with attendance and building our own program to calculate    `Net Salary` ?

Answer (score 1):

Install hr_payroll module. Flow is as below:
Employee --> Contracts --> Salary Structure --> Salary Rules

In Contract, You can set Working Schedule for that employee with Wage. You need to configure Salary Structure with Salary Rules as per your need. Salary rules for Bonus, expenses, etc.
In that Salary structure, You need to add that rules. Now, go to the Employee Payslip menu, select that employee, Related information will be automatically come over there. Click on Compute sheet button. You will get Salary details in Salary Computation tab as per your Salary rules that you added in your Salary Structure.

For now, there is no link between attendance and payroll in OpenERP that you need to customize. It depends on requirements that how much time it will take for that! Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Priyesh Solanki , But I know there is attendance (Sign in & Sing out Action) . Can you tell me how to reach it and linked with monthly salary
What we need is if the employee Absence for one day for example the detection from salary money for that day

Comment: I think @Don Kirkby can replay to this question and help in this topic